# Google Apps Script XmlService - search by attribute

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xml-parsing

Is there a simple method to locate an XML node by its attribute in Google Apps Script? Here's an XML snippet:

```
<hd:components>
    <hd:text name="ADM Custom admissions TE">
        <hd:prompt>Admission</hd:prompt>
        <hd:columnWidth widthType="minimum" minWidth="100"/>
    </hd:text>
    <hd:text name="ADM Insufficient heat end date TE">
        <hd:prompt>To</hd:prompt>
    </hd:text>
    <hd:text name="ADM Insufficient heat start date TE">
        <hd:prompt>From</hd:prompt>
    </hd:text>
    <hd:text name="ADM Third party payment period TE">
        <hd:defMergeProps unansweredText="__________"/>
        <hd:prompt>When (date or period)?</hd:prompt>
    </hd:text>
```

For purposes of the XML file I'm trying to parse, the "name" attribute is a unique identifier, while what GAS thinks is the "name" for purposes of the XmlService.Element.getChild(name) method ("text" for each node shown in this snippet) is a non-unique classifier for the type of node. I'd like to be able to write a function to retrieve a specific node from this XML file with only the name attribute. XMLPath notation in other languages has this capability using the [@ notation. Is there a way to do it in GAS, or do I need to write a function that walks through the XML until it finds a node with the right name attribute, or store it in some different type of data structure for fast searching if the XML file is sufficiently large?

Here's the snippet I started writing: it's fine if there's no built-in function, I just wondered if there was a better/faster way to do this. My function isn't so efficient, and I wondered if the XmlService had a more efficient internal data structure it's using to speed up searching.  My approach is just to loop through all of the element's children until there's a match.

```
function getComponentFromXML(xml,name) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) { 
    var x = xml[i];
    var xname = x.getAttribute('name').getValue();
    if (xname == name) {
      return getComponentAttributes(x);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you already check the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/) of Google Apps Script about XmlService and the attribute?

Comment: I did, and I didn't see a method that's already defined to search based on attribute. It's not a big function, I just worry about doing it a non-standard an unoptimized way, especially as it's available in Xpath and other XML implementations in different languages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in search, so the only way is to read the list of elements looking for the one with the desired value of attribute 'name'. If `elements` is an array of elements to search through, you can do

```
var searchResults = elements.filter(function (e) {
  return e.getAttribute('name') && e.getAttribute('name').getValue() == searchString;
});
```

(Both checks are needed to avoid an error when there is no 'name' attribute at all.)

How to obtain such an array `elements` may depend on XML document. If, as in your example, the elements to search are the immediate children of the root element, then

```
var doc = XmlService.parse(xmlString);
var elements = doc.getRootElement().getChildren();
```

would be a quick and easy way to do this.

In general, to get all elements without recursion, the `getDescendants` method can be used. It returns an array of Content object, which can be filtered down to Element objects:

```
var elements = doc.getDescendants().filter(function (c) {
  return c.getType() == XmlService.ContentTypes.ELEMENT;
}).map(function (c) {
  return c.asElement();
});
```